# Drools - Decision tables not fired after upgrade version of drools

Tags: drools

I'm trying to upgrade my drools version from 7.15.0.Final to 7.27.0.Final.
But after this upgrade, the decision tables rules are not fired (although the .drl rules are all called, even if in the same package), and I get some errors under my unit tests.

I already tried to check if the packages are all correct under the RuleSet cell, but didn't solved my problem.
I've also checked all the Release Notes, but didn't see anything that impacts the way I'm running the rules.

```java
public T execute(String kBaseFactory, T fact) {

        final KieBase kieBase = getKBaseFactory().fromKieBaseName(kBaseFactory);

        final KieSessionConfiguration conf = KieServices.Factory.get().newKieSessionConfiguration();
        conf.setOption(ClockTypeOption.get("pseudo"));
        final KieSession ksession = kieBase.newKieSession(conf, null);

        ksession.insert(object);
        ksession.fireAllRules();
        ksession.dispose();

        return fact;
}
```

Can someone help?

Thanks!

Comment: We could, but we need some more information. Can you please create a minimal reproducer and upload it here? https://issues.jboss.org Thanks

Comment: "`I get some errors under my unit tests`" What kind of errors?